# Google App Engine Log - ms and cpu_ms

Tags: google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the exact meaning of time values in GAE log fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5945538/what-are-the-exact-meaning-of-time-values-in-gae-log-fields)

Log of Google App Engine shows two different execution times “ms” and “cpu_ms”.

What is the different between both of them?

How can I explain execution behavior of an application for the following log entries?

```
a - ms=2443 cpu_ms=539
b - ms=8105 cpu_ms=14779
```